# Override Taxonomy Term Path to Contextually Filtered View

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, path-aliases

This may be highly specific, but I still think it has value for sizable number of applications in the wild, so here we go:

- I have a View established using Contextual Filters
- The Contextual Filters run against Taxonomy Terms
- The Taxonomy Terms are fields in a Field Collection
- The results of the View are also Grouped by the Taxonomy Terms which are displayed as a Rendered Taxonomy Term (which links to the Taxonomy Term page)

I want to override the default linking in the Rendered Taxonomy Term to initiate the Contextual Filtering -- rather than visiting the Taxonomy Term page (which has no relevancy here).

I tried, what I thought should work, and overrode the Taxonomy Term paths (url alias) -- only to end up with the oft encountered "page not found" issue.

My other option is to remove the link in the Rendered Taxonomy Term to avoid confusing visitors; however, the value of being able to carve the master list (it's a phone directory - hence Field Collections and not full custom Content Type entries) into segments is appealing.

Anybody have any ideas or suggestions?

*I have overridden the template using taxonomy-term.tpl.php to remove the link (as noted in [How to remove link from rendered node title in view?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73926/how-to-remove-link-from-rendered-node-title-in-view) -- see the comment from @smile for concise directions.). Still open to suggestions on path overrides though.*

Comment: [Can I make a Views “Rendered Node” field not be linked to the original node?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41057/can-i-make-a-views-rendered-node-field-not-be-linked-to-the-original-node) looks promising. (I've got jQuery Update installed, so my Views UI doesn't alway ring true. I'll have to double check my options.)

Comment: I can confirm [the comment about the missing UI element re: linking](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/64930/35121), and the subsequent "no longer seems to work" added by @thirdender... though in this case the grouping I'm using might be throwing things off (tests in output as a field seem to confirm it doesn't work though).